# Getting resources from secondary module on Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to get some `R.string` resources from a secondary module on Android Studio. I have two differents modules. I can pass Applicacion Context onto my secundary module in order to call `getString(R.string....)` method.

Same string is on both string files. But none of them are accesible for me. This is what I'm doing inside my secondary module:

```
 Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.infraestructura);
```

I'm having same results when I use context received from main module:

```
cx.getString(R.string.infraestructura);
```

When I'm importing there the secondary module `R.string` file, I'm getting exception:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.mycompany.sima/es.mycompany.sima.HomeActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0b0047
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0b0047
```

and when I try importing main `R.string` file, I am getting errors during compiling time:

```
Error:(9, 21) error: package es.mycompany.sima does not exist <-- Import line
Error:(32, 125) error: package R does not exist <-- Reference to R
```

I have solved problem by using `cx.getResources().getString(R.string.infraestructura)` instead of `cx.getString(R.string.infraestructura)`. Nevertheless, I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

`Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.infraestructura);`
will only work for system resources (android.R.string...)

From a secondary module, you generally wouldn't call the app module's string resources due to cyclical dependecies (app -> sub module && sub module -> app).

From your app module, you should be able to reference the submodule string resources like this:
`getString(package.ofsubmodule.R.string.string_name);`

Depending on where you are calling the `cx.getResources or cx.getString` and how you are using or passing it, it could be referencing either the app or sub module's resources, you would have to show more of your code to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the data directly. You need to use the Content Provider to share any data between applications. If you are using the second module as a library check the build path correctly and make sure that the R is pointing to correct module by looking at import.

Comment: Both modules are compiled into one application